# Woocommerce add payment method outside of checkout and my account

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm building a site for a winery, which have one specific requirement that is similar to a subscription, but a little different. Wine clubs are charged on a regular interval, but only two or three times a year and the amount is different every time. So, when a user signs up for the club, I want to collect their credit card information, but not charge it. On the wine club signup page, I need to have the credit card fields, which then need to be tokenized and sent to the gateway provider.

I tried the add_payment_method function in the gateway, but that redirects the user back to the My Account pages, which I don't want. Next, I'm going to try creating a dummy order and processing that to add the payment method. Has anyone run into this issue and found a way to solve it?

Note that I was able to do this with Stripe using some of the unique methods in their gateway, but I am looking for a solution that would support any of the token-supporting gateways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that payment token handling is not standardized across payment gateways in WooCommerce. I ended up having to use a bunch of conditional logic to deal with differences in the way gateways handle the add_pament_method function. Not ideal, but I'm not anticipating needing to support more than a couple gateways, so it's tolerable.